# How to Debug Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am hitting an issue where Selenium is not behaving as expected.
In my Python script, I search for a item by id. If the Node is visible, I then click the node and take a screenshot.

However, this is not working as expected. Selenium is taking rogue actions and the screenshots without the node being clicked.

Looking for guidance on why this is happening and how I can troubleshoot.

```
nodeWithMaxDropsEle = driver.find_elements_by_id(nodeWithMaxDropsId)[0]
print('nodeWithMaxDropsEle: ', nodeWithMaxDropsEle)

if nodeWithMaxDropsEle.is_displayed():
    nodeWithMaxDropsEle.click()
    print('Element: nodeWithMaxDropsEle visible')
else: 
    print('Element: nodeWithMaxDropsEle not visible')

time.sleep(3)
driver.save_screenshot("scshot-after-3.png")
```

Comment: What exactly is happening when you say `not working as expected`? What makes you feel `Selenium is taking rogue actions`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. The problem was that I was using `click_and_hold`incorrectly:

```
action_chains.move_to_element(pathDepthSelector) \
             .click_and_hold(pathDepthSelector) \
             .move_to_element(target).perform()
```

I subsequently replaced it with `drag_and_drop` and it works:

```
action_chains.drag_and_drop(pathDepthSelector, target).perform()
```

Still looking for guidance on how I can log to screen any actions that Selenium takes. Like in this example, the `click_and_hold` continued to be active causing erroneous results.